# Syntax error in partial function application

Tags: lambda, sml, smlnj, ml

I'm trying to use manipulated lambda expressions in SML NJ, and for some reason it raises error. the code in my "program.sml":

```
 fun add x y = x + y;  // (x. y. A x y) 
 fun plus = add 1;  // (x. y. A x y) 1 --> (y. A 1 y) -(e.g.)plus 4=5
```

Error after command 'use "program.sml" in ubuntu terminal:

```
 program.sml:2.5-2.9 Error: can't find function arguments in clause
 uncaught exception Error
 raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
         ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
         ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:292.17-292.20
```

It's definitely the "plus" line, because otherwise there is no error. and I've tried 'fun plus = (add 1);' (parentheses), which raises the same error. 
Maybe I'm missing a package, or whatever. can anyone explain that ?

Comment: A function that adds one to its input might be called `incr` or `succ`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
fun add x y= x + y;
```

You are (correctly) defining a function. Its type is

```
fn: int -> int -> int
```

which means that it is a higher-order function which takes an `int` as input and returns a *function* of `int -> int` as output.

You now need to just *use* this function to define a new value, `plus` (which happens to be a function in its own right).

Thus (as @jacobm has already pointed out), simply use:

```
val plus = add 1;
```

The subtlety is that in SML functions are "first-class values". In addition to *defining* them at the top-level using `fun` you can freely create them and pass them around as ordinary values. One of the reasons for defining a function in a curried form (the way you defined `add`) is that you can use it as a function factory that can be used to create functions as needed without explicitly defining them.

By the way, the title of your question is somewhat misleading. In SML the phrase "lambda expression" is usually reserved for anonymous functions created using `fn`. The lambda calculus syntax  `x.` is equivalent to `fn x =>` in SML. If you wanted to define `add` explicitly as a lambda expression you would use:

```
val add = fn x => fn y => x + y;
```

Note that lambda expressions don't need the keyword `fun` to define.

Answer (score 4):

`val plus`, not `fun plus`. `fun plus` is special syntax for defining a function by giving the function's body; `val plus` means "define the name `plus` as whatever's on the right-hand side," which in this case happens to be a function.